# how to combine two select statement

Tags: sql

I have those three tables in my database:

Posts:

[image]

Users:

[image]

Followers:

[image]

I wrote this query that retrieve the posts of the people you follow and your own posts

```
SELECT *  
FROM posts 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT follower_id 
                  FROM followers 
                  WHERE id = 1)
   OR user_id = 1
```

Number one above is a place holder for the logged in user.

Select statement for user:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_img  
FROM users 
WHERE id IN (SELECT follower_id 
             FROM followers 
             WHERE id = 1)
   OR user_id = 1
```

How to combine those two statement into one?

What I want to do is to use the results of the nested loop above (ie: followers ids) to get their first name, last name and their profile image, beside posts date from the first select statement all as one record

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output , also tag your dbms

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.ks, t1.[# Tasks], COALESCE(t2.[# Late], 0) AS [# Late]
FROM 
    (SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Tasks' FROM Table GROUP BY ks) t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT ks, COUNT(*) AS '# Late' FROM Table WHERE Age > Palt GROUP BY ks) t2
ON (t1.ks = t2.ks);
```